# Is there a dplyr::filter() parameter equivalent to nomatch option in data.table?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, data.table, drop

## With data.table

You can choose between either *nomatch=NA*:

```
DT[c("A", "D"), on = "V4", nomatch = NA] #returns a row with "D" even if not found
```

or *nomatch=NULL* (same behaviour as dplyr):

```
DT[c("A", "D"), on = "V4", nomatch = 0] # keep only rows found in V4
```

## With dplyr

```
filter(DF, V4 %in% c("A", "D")) # we only have equivalent to *nomatch=0* behaviour.
```

Comment: dplyr's filter is not well corresponding to DT's `i` argument which behaves as R's subset, try: `pi[1:2]`

Comment: _right outer join_ is the proper operation to reflect that using dplyr, so I think @Edo answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the same output of `DT[c("A", "D"), on = "V4", nomatch = NA]`

```
df %>% right_join(data.frame(V4 = c("A", "D")), "V4")
```

---

Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(V4 = LETTERS[c(1,1,2,2,3)], V3 = 1:5)
df %>% right_join(data.frame(V4 = c("A", "D")), "V4")
#>   V4 V3
#> 1  A  1
#> 2  A  2
#> 3  D NA

library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[c("A", "D"), on = "V4", nomatch = NA]
#>    V4 V3
#> 1:  A  1
#> 2:  A  2
#> 3:  D NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to know if there was a specific syntax to perform such an operation, or if it would be worthy for computation purposes to add such an option in dplyr. But it seems that's not the case.

Comment: So my answer is not what you’re looking for..?

Comment: It does the stuff I want, so I will answer yes. However, it would be nice if dplyr administrators add directly such an option in dplyr package.

Comment: You can try to open an issue on dplyr